# how can you reduce the speed of entering characters selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My automatic test gives the word "MyApplication", it does it very quickly, I need the word to be typed in about 0.5-0.7 seconds. I know I can use time.sleep, but I would like to know another solution, how can I do it differently?
I do not want time.sleep, because the query to the server goes only 300 ms and can not be changed. Fast typing causes the test to not work.

yes this is an automatic test. Inscription to input entered by the send keys method.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clikable((By.XPATH, "myypath"))
)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "myypath").send_keys("MyApplication")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  I'm not entirely clear on the problem you face; is it trying to retard the automation's output?

Comment: yes this is an automatic test.
Inscription to input entered by the send keys method.

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "myypath").send_keys("MyApplication")

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  When the requested code is up, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I added my code, it's only two lines. First I'm waiting for element, and then I use send_keys method, thank you

Answer (score 4):

Either introduce a delay which will match the minimum acceptable time that the page can handle:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def send_delayed_keys(element, text, delay=0.3) :
    for c in text :
        endtime = time.time() + delay
        element.send_keys(c)
        time.sleep(endtime - time.time())


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search")

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name="q"]')
send_delayed_keys(element, "abcdef", 0.6)
```

Or send each key and wait for no pending request:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

def send_autocomplete_keys(element, text) :
    ajax = AjaxWaiter(element.parent)

    for c in text :
        element.send_keys(c)
        ajax.wait_idle()


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search")

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name="q"]')
send_autocomplete_keys(element, "abcdef")
```

```py
class AjaxWaiter(object):

    JS_IS_XHR_IDLE = """\
if (!('active' in XMLHttpRequest))(function (){
  var _send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
  function _onrelease(){ --XMLHttpRequest.active };
  function _onloadend(){ setTimeout(_onrelease, 1) };
  XMLHttpRequest.active = 0;
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function send() {
    ++XMLHttpRequest.active;
    this.addEventListener('loadend', _onloadend, true);
    _send.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();
return XMLHttpRequest.active == 0;
"""

    def __init__(self, driver, timeout=10, frequency=0.08) :
        self.driver = driver
        self.waiter = WebDriverWait(self, timeout, frequency)
        self.driver.execute_script(self.JS_IS_XHR_IDLE)

    def is_idle(self) :
        return self.driver.execute_script(self.JS_IS_XHR_IDLE)

    def wait_idle(self) :
        self.waiter.until(AjaxWaiter.is_idle, "Pending requests")
```

Comment: First is very nice, use good :), but I have a question, can I create this without time.sleep? I talk about:
`
from selenium import webdriver

`
def send_delayed_keys(element, text, delay=0.3) :
    for c in text :
        endtime = time.time() + delay
        element.send_keys(c)
        time.sleep(endtime - time.time())
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search")
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name="q"]')
send_delayed_keys(element, "abcdef", 0.6)`

Comment: use the second example if you don't want to wait a defined time.

Comment: @FlorentB. 
I never thought of a solution with a function external to selenium to reduce the speed of writing characters

Thank you